# How do I change which of my projects a call to the Google Programmable Search Engine/Element Paid API uses?

Tags: google-api

I am making calls to the Google Programmable Search Engine/Element Paid API googleapis.com/customsearch/v1.  I want to change which project it refers to.
What controls that?
Does each project have a Search Engine key?
Does each Search Engine key have a project?
Should I create a new Search Engine?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: “How do I” = What procedure do I follow in order to accomplish the following?

“change” = Cause the value of a variable to be altered to a different value.

“which of my projects” = The variable is the identification of which project.

 “a call” = Running a computer program.

“to the Google Programmable Search Engine/Element Paid API” = The application in which the computer program is running.

“uses” = The value that will be processed by the computer program.

? = The preceding is a question.